# Plot line graph with different colors of specific average values of a column

Tags: r, average, linegraph

I have a dataset like this:

```
Year  Type Return
1900   A   2
1900   B   4
1901   A   7
1901   A   9
1901   B   6
1901   B   5
1903   B   5
1906   A   5
```

I have yearly information about two types and the correspondent return.
It can have more than one type per year, but can also repeat a type in the same year. It can also have an year with just one type, and some missing years.

I would like to plot a line graph with colors (maybe ggplot) that shows the evolution of the returns of A and B throughout time. (x axis Year, y axis Return).
When there is more than one piece of information in a year (such as in 1901 when we have two A's) we should average the returns (for A: mean of 7 and 9).

The real database has >10k lines of info.

Bonus question: it would be great if I could also have a separate version that instead of averaging the returns per year, sums the returns in each year (for A: 7+9)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dummy <- read.table(text = "Year  Type Return
1900   A   2
1900   B   4
1901   A   7
1901   A   9
1901   B   6
1901   B   5
1903   B   5
1906   A   5", header = T)

dummy %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year, Type) %>%

  dplyr::summarize(m = mean(Return),
            s = sum(Return)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = Type)) +
  geom_line(aes(Year, m)) +
  geom_line(aes(Year, s), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

```
dummy1 <-   dummy %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year, Type) %>%
  
  dplyr::summarize(m = mean(Return),
                   s = sum(Return))
```

## Mean

```
dummy1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = Type)) +
  geom_line(aes(Year, m))
```

## Sum

```
dummy1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = Type)) +
  geom_line(aes(Year, s))
```

## Bar

```
dummy1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, s,fill = Type)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

## Bar + x axis

```
dummy1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, s,fill = Type)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dummy1$Year), max(dummy1$Year)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can we please have two different graphs, one with returns mean and one with returns sum?

Comment: @DanielCosta I add the code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

If I wanted to plot the SUM part with a bar graph, to compare the size of A and B throughout time. So one bar would have an A part (in a color) and a B part (in another color) and we could see throughout the years the size of A and B and their interaction, would that be possible?

like this:
https://chartio.com/assets/50552a/tutorials/charts/stacked-bar-charts/073137bf11f1c2226f68c3188128e28d66115622dcdecc9bc208a6d4117f53e8/stacked-bar-example-1.png

Comment: @DanielCosta What does `A and B and their interaction` means?

Comment: Sorry.
let's say A is oats and B is milk. The return sum would be the total amount of A and B that is used.

I want to have a graph like the one in the link that shows, throughout time, how milk and oats have been combined... Eg. if the amount of oats to milk is increasing

Comment: @DanielCosta I add code for barplot above. What do you need further from that plot?

Comment: It worked, great, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the Axis, can i have all years in x axis? currently it has 1990, 2000, 2010...

Comment: @DanielCosta Does `have` means that 1990, 1991, ..., 2009, 2010,.... are need to shown in x axis?

Comment: Yes, if possible

Comment: @DanielCosta I add the code above. You can use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = ...)` to set x axis ticks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all..  you are the best